# Passing a function to wxWidgets thread-pool with inter-thread communication

Tags: c++, threadpool, wxwidgets

I am a hobby programmer learning C++ and multi-threading, and getting started on my first thread-pool attempt.

I use Code::Blocks 20.3, wxWidgets 3.1.4, and MinGW 17.1 on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

I have tried several thread-pool examples, but all blocked the GUI.

I found an example shown in https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication
that uses detached threads in a pool. This should not block the GUI.

I have "restructured" the 1 file example to work in a test project (gui, app, main, thread-pool modules).
I placed the classes in their own file, and moved the "main" part to the Main.cpp in my test project and replaced the gui code with a separate class file.
The standard example works as expected.

In the example, strings are passed to the thread-pool and other strings back to the main thread.
I have been searching for main thread AddToQueue() to pass any function like e.g. aTask() (void, or returning something to the main thread) that executes in the thread-pool. My search was not successful :-(.

=== Simple Task to be executed in a thread ===

```
std::vector<wxString> wxThreadCom2Frame::aTask(wxString wsSomeString, int x)
{
    std::vector<wxString> vTest{};
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        wxString wsTest{};
        wsTest << wsSomeString << " [" << i << "]";
        vTest.push_back(wsTest);
    }

    return vTest;
}
```

=== Or as alternative, pass the vector by reference

```
aTask(_T("Just some text"), 5, &vTest); // to be queued with AddJob
```

===

```
void wxThreadCom2Frame::aTask(wxString wsSomeString, int x, std::vector<wxString> *vTest)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        wxString wsTest{};
        wsTest << wsSomeString << " [" << i << "]\n";
        vTest->push_back(wsTest);
    }
}
```

===

I hope someone can help me understand how to do this.

This is the first step to what I actually like to achieve.
An 'extraction' function returns a structure of 20 tags from a music file (mp3, flac, etc).
The main 'collecting' function will call the 'extraction' function for each file (up to 7000) in a list and place it in the queue of the thread-pool.
The 'collecting' function returns a vector of structures to the main thread for further processing.

Regards, Ruud.

=== ThreadCom.cpp ===

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Inter-Thread_and_Inter-Process_communication //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Standard
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <map>
#include <list>

// wxWidgets
#include <wx/frame.h>
#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>
#include <wx/app.h>

class tJOB
{
  public:
    enum tCOMMANDS // list of commands that are currently implemented
    {
      eID_THREAD_EXIT=wxID_EXIT, // thread should exit or wants to exit
      eID_THREAD_NULL=wxID_HIGHEST+1, // dummy command
      eID_THREAD_STARTED, // worker thread has started OK
      eID_THREAD_JOB = ID_THREAD_JOB, // process normal job
      eID_THREAD_JOBERR = ID_THREAD_JOBERR // process erroneous job after which thread likes to exit
    }; // enum tCOMMANDS

    tJOB() : m_cmd(eID_THREAD_NULL) {}
    tJOB(tCOMMANDS cmd, const wxString& arg) : m_cmd(cmd), m_Arg(arg) {}
    tCOMMANDS m_cmd; wxString m_Arg;
}; // class tJOB

class QUEUE
{
  public:
    enum tPRIORITY { eHIGHEST, eHIGHER, eNORMAL, eBELOW_NORMAL, eLOW, eIDLE }; // priority classes
    QUEUE(wxEvtHandler* pParent) : m_pParent(pParent) {}

    void AddJob(const tJOB& job, const tPRIORITY& priority=eNORMAL) // push a job with given priority class onto the FIFO
    {
      wxMutexLocker lock(m_MutexQueue); // lock the queue
      m_Jobs.insert(std::make_pair(priority, job)); // insert the prioritized entry into the multimap
      m_QueueCount.Post(); // new job has arrived: increment semaphore counter
    } // void AddJob(const tJOB& job, const tPRIORITY& priority=eNORMAL)

    tJOB Pop()
    {
      tJOB element;
      m_QueueCount.Wait(); // wait for semaphore (=queue count to become positive)
      m_MutexQueue.Lock(); // lock queue
      element=(m_Jobs.begin())->second; // get the first entry from queue (higher priority classes come first)
      m_Jobs.erase(m_Jobs.begin()); // erase it
      m_MutexQueue.Unlock(); // unlock queue
      return element; // return job entry
    } // tJOB Pop()

    void Report(const tJOB::tCOMMANDS& cmd, const wxString& sArg=wxEmptyString, int iArg=0) // report back to parent
    {
      wxCommandEvent evt(wxEVT_THREAD, cmd); // create command event object
      evt.SetString(sArg); // associate string with it
      evt.SetInt(iArg);
      m_pParent->AddPendingEvent(evt); // and add it to parent's event queue
    } // void Report(const tJOB::tCOMMANDS& cmd, const wxString& arg=wxEmptyString)

    size_t Stacksize() // helper function to return no of pending jobs
    {
      wxMutexLocker lock(m_MutexQueue); // lock queue until the size has been read
      return m_Jobs.size();
    }

  private:
    wxEvtHandler* m_pParent;
    std::multimap<tPRIORITY, tJOB> m_Jobs; // multimap to reflect prioritization: values with lower keys come first, newer values with same key are appended
    wxMutex m_MutexQueue; // protects queue access
    wxSemaphore m_QueueCount; // semaphore count reflects number of queued jobs
};

class WorkerThread : public wxThread
{
  public:
    WorkerThread(QUEUE* pQueue, int id=0) : m_pQueue(pQueue), m_ID(id) { assert(pQueue); wxThread::Create(); }

  private:
    QUEUE* m_pQueue;
    int m_ID;

    virtual wxThread::ExitCode Entry()
    {
      Sleep(1000); // sleep a while to simulate some time-consuming init procedure
      tJOB::tCOMMANDS iErr;
      m_pQueue->Report(tJOB::eID_THREAD_STARTED, wxEmptyString, m_ID); // tell main thread that worker thread has successfully started
      try { while(true) OnJob(); } // this is the main loop: process jobs until a job handler throws
      catch(tJOB::tCOMMANDS& i) { m_pQueue->Report(iErr=i, wxEmptyString, m_ID); } // catch return value from error condition
      return (wxThread::ExitCode)iErr; // and return exit code
    } // virtual wxThread::ExitCode Entry()

    virtual void OnJob()
    {
      tJOB job=m_pQueue->Pop(); // pop a job from the queue. this will block the worker thread if queue is empty
      switch(job.m_cmd)
      {
      case tJOB::eID_THREAD_EXIT: // thread should exit
        Sleep(1000); // wait a while
        throw tJOB::eID_THREAD_EXIT; // confirm exit command
      case tJOB::eID_THREAD_JOB: // process a standard job
        Sleep(2000);
        m_pQueue->Report(tJOB::eID_THREAD_JOB, wxString::Format(wxT("Job #%s done."), job.m_Arg.c_str()), m_ID); // report successful completion
        break;
      case tJOB::eID_THREAD_JOBERR: // process a job that terminates with an error
        m_pQueue->Report(tJOB::eID_THREAD_JOB, wxString::Format(wxT("Job #%s erroneous."), job.m_Arg.c_str()), m_ID);
        Sleep(1000);
        throw tJOB::eID_THREAD_EXIT; // report exit of worker thread
        break;
      case tJOB::eID_THREAD_NULL: // dummy command
      default:
          break; // default
      } // switch(job.m_cmd)
    } // virtual void OnJob()
}; // class WorkerThread : public wxThread
```

=== partial wxThreadCom2Main.cpp ===

```
void wxThreadCom2Frame::AddToQueue( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    int iJob=rand();
    m_pQueue->AddJob(tJOB((tJOB::tCOMMANDS)event.GetId(), wxString::Format(wxT("%u"), iJob)));
    SetStatusText(wxString::Format(wxT("Job #%i started."), iJob)); // just set the status text
}

void wxThreadCom2Frame::OnThread(wxCommandEvent& event) // handler for thread notifications
{
    switch(event.GetId())
    {
        case tJOB::eID_THREAD_JOB:
            // Get the returned vector and do something with it
            SetStatusText(wxString::Format(wxT("[%i]: %s"), event.GetInt(), event.GetString().c_str())); // progress display
            break;
        case tJOB::eID_THREAD_EXIT:
            SetStatusText(wxString::Format(wxT("[%i]: Stopped."), event.GetInt()));
            m_Threads.remove(event.GetInt()); // thread has exited: remove thread ID from list
            if(m_Threads.empty()) { EnableControls(false); } // disable some menu items if no more threads
            break;
        case tJOB::eID_THREAD_STARTED:
            SetStatusText(wxString::Format(wxT("[%i]: Ready."), event.GetInt()));
            EnableControls(true); // at least one thread successfully started: enable controls
            break;
        default:
            event.Skip();
    }
}

void wxThreadCom2Frame::EnableControls(bool bEnable) // en/dis-able Stop, Add Job, Add JobErr
{
    wxMenu* pMenu=GetMenuBar()->GetMenu(0);
    static const int MENUIDS[]={/*ID_START_THREAD, */ID_THREAD_EXIT, ID_THREAD_JOB, ID_THREAD_JOBERR};
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<WXSIZEOF(MENUIDS); pMenu->Enable(MENUIDS[i++], bEnable));
}
```

===

Comment: Passing a function pointer from the gui thread to secondary threads is a bad idea.  The function will be executed in the context of the secondary thread and if it tries to call any wxWidgets GUI functions it can crash your program.  The best method for communication is to use your queue to send messages to the secondary threads and wxThreadEvent to send messages back to the main one. With [SetPayload](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread_event.html#a4b9b438e229a0f53c97e6058cfc67959), you should be able to pass the information as you need to do whatever you want.

Comment: @New Pagodi. Thank you for your advice. I will return through messages. The remaining question is how to add the aTask() function to the queue (along with a message). From what I can see is that SetPayload is for data, not for functions.